# On archive.php show loop for child categories if they exist or posts if they don't, on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type 'sch_keynote', with custom taxonomy 'sch_keynotegroups'. On the archive page I have managed to create two loops, one for child categories and one for posts. I only want to show one or the other, so have used the terms query to show or hide. This almost works, however when just the child categories are showing the 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' and pagination still show up. I can't can't quite work out why. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php
$term          = get_queried_object();
$term_id       = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
$termchildren  = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

if ( !empty( $termchildren ) ) {
  ?>

  <div class="subcatwrapper">
    <ul class="workshopgrid centerWidth">
 
    <?php
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
      $term      = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
      $term_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy );
      ?>
      <li class="workshopbox">
        <div class="workshopimage">
          <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $catimg; ?>" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="workshopTitle">
          <h6>
            <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="workshopTitle"><p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p></div>
        <div class="workshopButton">
          <p>
            <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" class="whiteButton">Discover More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <?php
    } // End foreach
    ?>

  </ul>
</div>

<?php
} // End if

if ( have_posts() && ( empty( $termchildren ) ) ) : ?>
  <div class="centerWidth centreme">
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter id="7085"]' ); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="workshopwrapper">
    <ul class="workshopgrid centerWidth">

    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <li class="workshopbox">
        <div class="workshopimage">
          <div class="article">
            <div class="blogthumbnail>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'letterbox' ); ?>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="workshopTitle">
              <h6>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="workshopTitle">
              <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="workshopButton">
              <p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="whiteButton">Discover More</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>

    </ul>
  </div>

<?php
else:
  ?>

  <h6><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></h6>
  <div class="navigation centerWidth clearfix">
    <?php
    the_posts_pagination( array(
      'mid_size'  => 2,
      'prev_text' => __( '<', 'textdomain' ),
      'next_text' => __( '>', 'textdomain' ),
    ) );
    ?>
  </div>

<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Correction to image call of child categories should be
`src="'.get_field('category_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id).'"/>`

Comment: I've edited your code to another style for the sake of readability. There were a number of instances of malformed markup in there - missing and mismatched closing tags, for the most part; this style makes it a lot easier to catch such things :) . It's also worth a mention that WordPress functions starting with a `the_` are "template tags" which output their return value instead of returning it - there's no need to `echo` them manually.

Answer (score 1):

This works, anything better would be appreciated

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
if (!empty($termchildren)) {
echo '<div class="subcatwrapper">';
echo '<ul class="workshopgrid centerWidth">';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
echo '<li class="workshopbox">';
echo '<div class="workshopimage"><a href="'. get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy ) .'" ><img  src="'.get_field('category_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id).'"/></a></div>';
echo '<div class="workshopTitle"><h6><a href="'.get_term_link( $term ->slug, $term ->taxonomy ).'">';
echo $term ->name.'</a></h6></div>';
echo '<div class="workshopTitle"><p>'.$term->description.'</p></div>';
echo '<div class="workshopButton"><p><a href="'. get_term_link( $term ->slug, $term ->taxonomy ).'" class="whiteButton">Discover More</a></p></div>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
} elseif (have_posts() && (!!empty($termchildren))) {
    echo '<div class="centerWidth centreme">';
//echo do_shortcode ('[searchandfilter id="7085"]');
echo '</div><div class="workshopwrapper"><ul class="workshopgrid centerWidth">';
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
echo '<li class="workshopbox"><div class="workshopimage">';
echo '<div class="article">';
echo '<div class="blogthumbnail"><a href="';
echo get_the_permalink($post->ID);
echo '">';
echo the_post_thumbnail($size = 'letterbox').'</a></div>';
echo '<div class="workshopTitle"><h6><a href="';
echo get_the_permalink($post->ID);
echo '">';
echo get_the_title($post->ID);
echo '</a></h6></div><div class="workshopTitle"><p>';
echo the_excerpt();
echo '</p></div><div class="workshopButton"><p><a href="';
echo get_the_permalink($post->ID);
echo '" class="whiteButton">Discover More</a></p></div></div></div></li>';
endwhile;
echo '</ul></div>';
echo '<div class="navigation centerWidth clearfix">';
echo the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( '<', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( '>', 'textdomain' ),
) );
} else {
echo '<h6><'._e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.').'</h6>';
}
```

Comment: I think this is a fine solution 

Comment: I've found an issue that I don't know how to resolve. If you go directly to the custom post using this /?post_type=sch_keynote, the script doesn't work and the page is broken. Any suggestions?